# Why does Python return negative list indexes?

Tags: python

If I have this list with 10 elements:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Why will l[10] return an IndexError, but l[-1] returns 0?

```
>>> l[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> l[0]
1
>>> l[-1]
0
>>> l[-2]
9
```

What I want to do is throw an error if there are no previous elements in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by "no previous elements in the list"?  If by "previous" you mean "to the left of the current element", then Lattyware's answer should serve nicely.  But I can't help but wonder if you mean something else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Python, negative list indices indicate items counted from the right of the list (that is, `l[-n]` is shorthand for `l[len(l)-n]`).

If you find you need negative indices to indicate an error, then you can simply check for that case and raise the exception yourself (or handle it then and there):

```
index = get_some_index()
if index < 0:
    raise IndexError("negative list indices are considered out of range")
do_something(l[index])
```

Comment: Not quite sure I like the IndexError - but at least it now has a message. I would be quite surprised if I couldn't get the last element using -1 when I *know* it's a builtin list...Plus extended slicing needs some work on it...

Comment: @JonClements I'm not suggesting a subclass, so the list won't *behave* differently, just in the particular instance where you don't want negative indices to be possible, deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `l[-1]` is equal to `l[len(l)-1]`, 
similarly `l[-2]` is equal to `l[len(l)-2]`

```
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> lis[-1],lis[-2],lis[-3]
(5, 4, 3)
>>> lis[len(lis)-1],lis[len(lis)-2],lis[len(lis)-3]
(5, 4, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q**: Why will `l[10]` return an `IndexError`, but `l[-1]` returns `0`?

**A**: Because index values in Python (as in many other languages) are zero-based. That means the first item is stored at index `0`.

Your list

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

has 10 items. Since the index starts at `0`, the last item will be at index `9`. When you try to access your list at index `10`, Python rightly throws an `IndexError` exception to tell you that this is not a valid index value and is out of bounds.

Python also uses the convention of negative index values to access items from the "end" of a list or sequence. Index value `-1` indicates the *last* item in the list, `-2` the next-to-last etc. Since the last item in your list is `0`, this is what `l[-1]` returns.

@Lattyware's answer already shows you how to generate/throw an exception, I hope this answers your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Because, index value starts from 0. In your case the last index value is 9, no more index value after 9. when you try print the values beyond the index value limit, it must throws an error