# How to assign the last character of a string to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to store the last character of a string in a variable without knowing beforehand how long the string is (the string is originally read from a list). I have:

```
last = record[-1]
lastInd = len(last) - 1
lastChar = last[lastInd]
```

But I get the following error:

```
lastChar = last[lastInd]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

If I try:

```
lastChar = last[-1]
```

I get the same error:

```
lastChar = last[-1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I don't really understand what's going wrong here? Am I not getting the index right?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error you get. What does `record` look like?

Comment: What type does ``record`` have?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235227/2089675) to learn about negative indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `last` is an empty string.

Check this out:

```
>>> last = 'a'
>>> last[-1]
'a'
>>> last = ''
>>> last[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

If you want an empty string for your last character, just in case you have an empty string as your last record, then you could try this:

```
if last == '': # or `if not last`
    lastChar = ''
```

Alternatively, you could use the ternary operator:

```
lastChar = last[-1] if last else ''
```

Comment: No, then the first line will fail

Comment: @Haidro: That was a direct paste of my python 3.3.2 session. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You made `last = ''` for some reason :p

Comment: @Haidro: The first line is `last = 'a'`. And it works. The second (well, third) is `last = ''`. And of course that fails, but that's the whole point of the question, and of this answer.

Comment: I was demonstrating how the OP's problem stems from an attempt to read the last character out of an empty string. This is why I demonstrated attempting to read one non-empty and one empty string

Comment: Sorry - @inspectorG4dget If you edit your question I will happily remove my downvote

Comment: This is exactly the problem! I figured it out just before reading this.. now to figure out the logic to assign an empty string to lastChar if record[-1] is empty...

Comment: @user1844098 Use slicing: `lastChar = last[-1:]`. Abarnert explains this

Comment: Slicing is an excellent idea. I wish I'd thought of it. I've also updated my post with another idea, though

Comment: You shouldn't write `if last == '':`; just use `if last:`. Empty strings are falsey, non-empty strings are truthy, and, as PEP 8 explains, it's clearer to write code that uses that than to try to guess the right thing to test against.

Comment: @Haidro: Although I do explain the slicing solution, I don't recommend it for a novice. Unless you understand why a slice of a string and an index of a string are both the same type, it's just going to confuse you.

Comment: @abarnert: I included that in a code comment. But I've been bitten by `last = None` (which is also falsey) as an flagging value before, which is why I prefer this way these days. If you have a solution to that, I'm all ears

Comment: @abarnert When I learned python, I was never really confused, but your choice I guess

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: If `last` is a string, nothing you do to index it can return `None`. Adding in extra checks against things that can't happen makes your code more confusing, because people have to try to figure out what you were trying to protect against.

Comment: @abarnert: I suppose I should do `if last is not None and not last` then, which does make sense

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: But that's still protecting against something that can't possibly happen, so anyone reading your code will still have to study it to try to figure out where it could happen before finally proving to themselves that it can't.

Comment: @Haidro: But I suspect you never would have had this problem, or at least would have known how to print out `last` and find the answer yourself. Different people start learning Python at different background levels…

Comment: @abarnert: I meant that sometimes, I set `last = None` way before I assign it to the last character (which in this case would happen inside and if statement). Hence why I need to check against None. But that's assuming more about the problem and the code than OP has led on

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Assigning `None` and then testing for it everywhere in case it somehow missed all the code paths that should have defined it is an anti-pattern. The `NameError` you would have otherwise gotten is easier to debug, and harder to accidentally forget to deal with.

Comment: @abarnert: fair point. My missing this means my brain is tired-er than I thought. Good night, good people of SO!

Answer (score 5):

As inspectorG4dget says, the only way you can get this exception from `last[-1]` is if `last` is an empty string.

If you want to know how to deal with it… well, it depends on what you're trying to do.

Normally, if you're trying to get the last character of a string, you expect it to be non-empty, so it *should* be an error if it is unexpectedly empty.

But if you want to get the last character if the string is npt empty, or an empty string if it is, there are three ways to do it, in (what I think is) declining order of pythonic-ness, at least in code written by a novice.

First, there's [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) ("Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission). Assume it'll work, `try` it, and deal with unexpected failure as appropriate:

```
try:
    lastChar = last[-1]
except IndexError:
    lastChar = ''
```

Then there's [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) (Look Before You Leap). Check for unexpected cases in advance:

```
if last:
    lastChar = last[-1]
else:
    lastChar = ''
```

Finally, there's being overly clever. Write code that you won't understand three months from now without thinking it through:

```
lastChar = last[-1:]
```

This returns all characters from the last one to the end. If there are any characters, that's the same as the last one. If there are no characters, that's nothing.

Note that this only really works as intended because a string's individual elements are themselves strings. If you tried to get the last element from a list like this, you'd get a list of 1 element or an empty list, not a single possible-empty element.