# Extract a list without duplicates from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
id,created_at,username
1,2006-10-09T18:21:51Z,hey
2,2007-10-09T18:30:28Z,bob
3,2008-10-09T18:40:33Z,bob
4,2009-10-09T18:47:42Z,john
5,2010-10-09T18:51:04Z,brad
...
```

I contains 1M+ lines.
I'd like to extract the list of username without duplicate from it using python. So far my code looks like this:

```
import csv

file1 = file("sample.csv", 'r')
file2 = file("users.csv", 'w')

reader = csv.reader(file1)
writer = csv.writer(file2)

rownum = 0
L = []
for row in reader:
    if not rownum == 0:
        if not row[2] in L:
            L.append(row[2])
            writer.writerow(row[2])

    rownum += 1
```

I have several questions:
1 - my output in users.csv looks like this:

```
h,e,y
b,o,b
j,o,h,n
b,r,a,d
```

How do I remove the commas between each letter?

2 - My code is not very elegant, is there any way to import the csv file as a matrix to select the last row and then to use an elegant library like underscore.js in javascript to remove the duplicates?

Many thanks

Comment: you're not outputting csv data, so there's no point in using a `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `set` here, it provides `O(1)` item lookup compared to `O(N)` of lists.

```
seen = set()
add_  = seen.add
next(reader) #skip header
writer.writerows([row[-1]] for row in reader if row[-1] not in seen
                                                        and not add_(row[-1]))
```

And always use the `with` statement for handling files, it'll automatically close the file for you:

```
with file("sample.csv", 'r') as file1, file("users.csv", 'w') as file2:
    #Do stuff with file1 and file2 here
```

Comment: this code is way more elegant than my loops but I still get the commas between each letter. How come? Thanks!!

Comment: @Spearfisher Fixed that, try the updated version. You'll need to use a list: `['bob']` etc

Comment: thanks your fix worked - however why do you use -1 as index? Shouldn't it be 2 as im trying to get the 3rd column?

Comment: @Spearfisher `-1` means the last index, i.e 2 in your case. [Why does Python return negative list indexes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235213/why-does-python-return-negative-list-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
writer.writerow(row[2])
```

to

```
writer.writerow([row[2]])
```

Also, checking for membership in lists is computationally expensive [O(n)]. If you will be checking for membership in a large collection of items, and doing it often, use a `set` [O(1)]:

```
L = set()
reader.next() # Skip the header
for row in reader:
    if row[2] not in L:
        L.add(row[2])
        writer.writerow([row[2]])
```

#### Alternatively

If you're okay with using a few megabytes of memory, just do this:

```
with open("sample.csv", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    reader.next()
    no_duplicates = set(tuple(row) for row in reader)

    with open("users.csv", "wb") as outfile:
        csv.writer(outfile).writerows(no_duplicates)
```

if order is important, use an `OrderedDict` instead of a set:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("sample.csv", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    reader.next()
    no_duplicates = OrderedDict.fromkeys(tuple(row) for row in reader)

    with open("users.csv", "wb") as outfile:
        csv.writer(outfile).writerows(no_duplicates.keys())
```

Answer (score -1):

**Easy and short!**

```
for line in reader:
    string = str(line)
    split = string.split("," , 2)
    username = split[2][2:-2]
```