# Hard to understand the shortened form of python code

Tags: python

I came across these two lines while reading a file. I don't quite understand what it means exactly. Here nodes, edges, headnodeId, tailnodeId are lists. I really appreciate your help

```
def addInEdge( self, edge ):
    self.inEdges.append( edge )     
    self.totalEdgeCapacity += edge.capacity

def addOutEdge( self, edge ):
    self.outEdges.append( edge )        
    self.totalEdgeCapacity += edge.capacity

def addEdge(self, edge):
    self.edges.append( edge )
    self.nodes[ edge.headNodeId ].addInEdge( edge )
    self.nodes[ edge.tailNodeId ].addOutEdge( edge ) 

nodes[ edges[-1].headNodeId ].addInEdge( edges[-1] )
nodes[ edges[-1].tailNodeId ].addOutEdge( edges[-1] )
```

Comment: Is it the `[-1]` that's confusing you? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235227/645270), for example. Are you sure you mean that `headNodeId` and `tailNodeId` are lists?

Comment: `[-1]` gets the last element of the list. `[-2]` gets the second last and so on...

Comment: @keyser the list[list] syntax is confusing. Could you help me understand that thing? I'm sorry. Those are not lists but numbers that aren't ordered. I'm reading them from an xml file    <edges><edge capacity="183.2" costs="15.3" headNodeId="1" id="0" tailNodeId="0"/>

Comment: So they aren't lists? It looks like you have `list[index]` syntax then. I don't really understand your confusion.

Comment: Anything between the square brackets is an expression. That can be a simple index number (`5`), or another variable (`current_index`) or the result of a list object lookup. `edges[-1].headNodeId` takes the last object in `edges` and references the `headNodeId` attribute on that. That's one expression, the result of which is then used to index `nodes[]`.

Comment: I don't understand what is happening over here especially when the .addInEdge is being appended to the code and also the index that the list gets because of [edges[-1].headNodeId]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-thinking this and confusing yourself. This appears to be a representation of a directed graph: it looks like `edges` is a list of Edges, and each Edge has a `headNodeId` and a `tailNodeId`. Each of those IDs refers to a Node in the `nodes` list.

So all that's happening when you say `nodes[ edges[-1].headNodeId ]` is "give me the item from 'nodes' whose index is the head node ID of the last item in 'edges'". Then, the code is simply calling `addInEdge` on that Node.

A much more verbose version of this would be:

```
last_edge = edges[-1]
head_node_id = last_edge.headNodeId
head_node = nodes[head_node_id]
last_edge.addInEdge(head_node)
tail_node_id = last_edge.tailNodeId
tail_node = nodes[tail_node_id]
last_edge.addOutEdge(tail_node)
```

Comment: Ah....Okay...I got it. Thanks a lot Daniel. Really removed that cloud of confusion in my mind. Thank You. Could you point me out to a few sources where I can find this directed graph representation as well?

Comment: Hello Daniel, When I try appending the edges to the lists InEdges, OutEdges using addInEdge and addOutEdge method, I get this error saying `python work.py --output topology.xml --xml germany50.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work.py", line 307, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "work.py", line 300, in main
    nodes[ edges[-1].SourceID ].addInEdge( edges[-1] )
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'addInEdge'`. I am providing the link to the files I'm working on. Could you help me fix this?[https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8h321y7c9c60vt/AADzDj7oOM8YU76Ww6W4LIPYa]

Comment: You should ask a new question, and post a cut-down version of the code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I really wish I could but seems like my questions have been voted down and so I'm not able to ask another question but its really important to me and I've been trying all sorts of stuff for over a week and have failed to figure out the root cause. I believe this is what is causing the problem and I'm not so good with the classes too. `nodes[ edges[-1].headNodeId ].addInEdge( edges[-1] )
 nodes[ edges[-1].tailNodeId ].addOutEdge( edges[-1] )`